# Are there any CDNs that can be mounted like a filesystem

Tags: filesystems, mount, cdn

I am running a project with an architecture, that can currently serve content only from local filesystem. I want to store content at some CDN. Is there any way (or specific CDNs) I can mount a CDN as a filesystem?

Maybe there is some tool for it?

UPD. Platform-independent, if any.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use standard windows fire shares (which can be accessed by multiple users at once) mounted as drive letters - or you can use iSCSI which allows a remote storage volume to be used locally over IP. It looks like a 'local' disk instead of as a network drive, however only 1 computer can use a given iSCSI volume at any given time.

Windows has built-in support for both so take your pick.

Comment: And that's related to Content Distribution Networks exactly how?